# Spring HATEOAS templated link for void download method

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I have a method in my controller as below :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download/attachment/{attachmentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void download(@PathVariable("attachmentId") String attachmentId, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream file = myCustomObject.getAttachmentById(attachmentId);
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

I want to generate a templated HATEOAS link to this method using the ControllerLinkBuilder class that Spring provides. My link should look like :

```
"download" : {
          "href" : "https://localhost:8080/download/attachment/{attachmentId}"
}
```

I am using the following code to do that in my ResourceAssembler class (which extends ResourceAssemblerSupport) :

```
            Link downloadAttachmentLink = linkTo(MyRestController.class, MyRestController.class
                .getMethod("download", String.class, HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class),
                "{attachmentId}").withRel("download");
```

The link I am getting out of this is not templated. It is URL encoded. The "{" is sent as   %7B. I don't want that to happen. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I solved this problem using the following :

```
            Link downloadAttachmentByIdLink = new Link(
                new UriTemplate(
                        linkTo(MyRestController.class,
                                MyRestController.class.getMethod("download", String.class,
                                        HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class),
                                "").toUriComponentsBuilder().build().toUriString(),
                        new TemplateVariables(
                                new TemplateVariable("attachmentId", TemplateVariable.VariableType.SEGMENT))),
                "download");
```